# Swift 4 - How to switch between ViewControllers from a UITabBarController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using a UITabBarController and I would like to use a button in a view to move to the next view without having to click on the bar.
How could I do that programmatically ?

[image: Storyboard]

```
class PlayTableBarViewController: UITabBarController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
    }

    func nextView() {
        print(self.viewControllers!)
        self.selectedViewController = self.viewControllers![self.selectedIndex + 1]
        self.show(self.selectedViewController!, sender: nil)
    }
}

class StartVC: UIViewController {
    private var _fatherVC: PlayTableBarViewController?

    var fatherVC: PlayTableBarViewController {
        if _fatherVC == nil {
            _fatherVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "playViewController") as? PlayTableBarViewController
        }
        return _fatherVC!
    }

    @IBAction func backToGame(_ sender: UIButton) {
        fatherVC.nextView()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `selectedIndex` property of UITabBarController (until you want to have More section in your `UITabBar`.

From:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621171-selectedindex

> Setting this property changes the selected view controller to the one
>   at the designated index in the viewControllers array. To select the
>   More navigation controller itself, you must change the value of the
>   selectedViewController property instead.

```
class PlayTableBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    func nextView() {
        self.selectedIndex = self.selectedIndex + 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error where I initialize `_fatherVC`.  This:

```
_self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "playViewController")
     as? PlayTableBarViewController_
```

should be:

```
_fatherVC = self.tabBarController as? PlayTableBarViewController
```

Now it's working perfectly.